# Cannot format E: drive. It says it is a boot partition. But it isn't actually

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I have Winodows 8 installed in C: drive and 
I want to format my E: drive but I can't because it says it is a boot partition. I can see some boot files there too, don't know how they came!
Any solution?

Another question is, does it make any difference that some partition is logical or primary or extended?

Please reply anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can look it up from partition manager in some Linux Live CD. It will show with B flag if the partition is bootable.